# Bash Script issue, command not found, PATH seems to be correct

Tags: bash

I have a issue with my Script, i am just trying to fingure out if my screen session is running or not (line 19).
The rest of the script is working.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $PATH // /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
echo "0"
content=$(wget http://interwebs.com/index.php?page=count -q -O -)
z=$(($content / 5))
z=$(($z + 1))
echo $z // 4
lockfile=/var/tmp/mylock

if ( set -o noclobber; echo "$$" > "$lockfile") 2> /dev/null; then

        trap 'rm -f "$lockfile"; exit $?' INT TERM EXIT

        # do stuff here
        x=1
        count=0
        while [ $x -le $z ]
                do
                 $req ="$(ps -ef | grep -i mystatus$count | grep -v grep)"
                 if [ "$req" = "" ]; then
                 # run bash script
                 screen -amds mystatus$count /usr/bin/wget --spider interwebs.com/index.php?page=cronwhatsoever$(( $count +1))-$(( $count +5))
                else
                 echo "Cron running"
                fi
                x=$(( $x + 1 ))
                count=$(( $count +5))
        done
      # clean up after yourself, and release your trap
        rm -f "$lockfile"
        trap - INT TERM EXIT
else
        echo "Lock Exists: $lockfile owned by $(cat $lockfile)"
fi
sleep 15
```

It returns line 19: =: command not found. Actually running:

```
ps -ef | grep -i bukkit | grep -v grep
```

Works without issues if i run it directly in my Terminal, so any idea how to solve this issue?

I guess it something PATH related but grep is located in /bin/grep.

Comment: Hi @Neoon why don't you put a `set -x` at the beginning of your script?

Comment: For me , it is the `ps -ef`that is causing you problem. You should put a path in it

Comment: set -x (Debug) Output: http://pastebin.com/TcuZjqAy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
             $req ="$(ps -ef | grep -i mystatus$count | grep -v grep)"
```

should be

```
             req="$(ps -ef | grep -i mystatus$count | grep -v grep)"
```

Don't use `$` on the left-hand side of an assignment, and you must not have spaces around the `=`